# My if statement is doing the opposite of what I want it to do

Tags: c, if-statement, while-loop, linked-list, strcmp

I have a program that asks the user to input a word, and each word they enter is added to a linked list. When the user enters `"END"` the program is supposed to list all the nodes.

My problem is that the program only adds the word `"END"` into the list, and when the user enters anything else, the else condition is triggered: all the items in the list are printed out, but all these words are just `"END"`.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

struct node {
  char word[32];
  struct node *next;
};

int main() {
  struct node *head = NULL, *cur = NULL;
  char input[32];

  while(1) {
    cur = malloc(sizeof(struct node));

    printf("Enter words: ");
    scanf("%s", input);

    if (strcmp(input, "END") == 0) {
      cur->next = head;
      strcpy(cur->word, input);
      head = cur;
    } else {
      struct node *iter = head;

      while (iter != NULL) {
        printf("Contents: %s\n", iter->word);
        iter = iter->next;
      }
    }
  }
}
```

By making the if statement check if the condition `== 1` it just makes the user just keep entering words, regardless what the user inputs, such as`"END"`.

Any help would be much appreciated.

Comment: Then invert the `if`. `strcmp` is NOT guaranteed to return 1 or 0. It can return 0 or any other value. Check `strcmp(...) != 0`.

Comment: [`strcmp`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/c/string/byte/strcmp) returns `0` when the strings match. When the user enters "END" you need to [`break`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/c/language/break) out of the loop.

Comment: @CodeCharmander thanks, that worked. But I still don't get why. Could you please explain?

Comment: [strcmp()](https://en.cppreference.com/w/c/string/byte/strcmp) returns zero  if the strings match, a negative number if the first string is less than the second, or a positive number if the first string is greater than the second. It's a lexicographical comparison, not merely an equality comparison.

Comment: Ah, I didn't realise that is how it worked. I just Googled it too. I just thought it was either equal or not, as opposed to it returning a value.

Comment: If you don't add the break, you will still be inside the while(1) { ... } loop. So, after printing the contents of the list (in the else clause) it the code will fall out of the if (..._ {} else {} statement and then still go back to the top of the while(1) { ... } loop.

Comment: A macro like `#define streq(a, b) (strcmp((a), (b)) == 0)` may help if the `strcmp` syntax is confusing (like it is to many beginners). On the other hand, if you ever have to read other peoples' code, you have to remember how `strcmp` works anyway…

Answer (score 2):

The condition in the if statement

```
if (strcmp(input, "END") == 0)
```

means that the string stored in the array `input` is equal to the string literal `"END"`.  So if the array contains the string `"END"` you are inserting a new node in the list.

Also you have to allocate memory for a new node after this check not before it. Otherwise there will be memory leaks.

Pay attention to that you have an infinite loop.

And you need to free all allocated memory.

It seems you mean something like the following

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <ctype.h>

#define N   32

struct node 
{
    char word[N];
    struct node *next;
};

int main(void) 
{
    struct node *head = NULL;
    char input[N];

    printf( "Enter words: " );

    while ( scanf( "%31s", input ) == 1 )
    {
        char tmp[N];

        size_t i = 0;

        while ( ( tmp[i] = toupper( ( unsigned char )input[i] ) ) != '\0' ) ++i;

        if ( strcmp( tmp, "END" )  == 0 ) break;

        struct node *current = malloc( sizeof( struct node ) );
        strcpy( current->word, input );
        current->next = head;
        head = current;
    }

    for ( struct node *current = head; current != NULL; current = current->next )
    {
        printf( "%s -> ", current->word );
    }

    puts( "NULL" );

    while ( head != NULL )
    {
        struct node *current = head;
        head = head->next;
        free( current );
    }

    return 0;
}
```

The program output will look like

```
Enter words: Jackson Jake Hello end
Hello -> Jake -> Jackson -> NULL
```

Answer (score 1):

First, you need to add strings to list until input string is `END` by using `strcmp() != 0` when comparison is non-zero.

Second, the current `cur` node is created which contains new string add need to have a tail pointer for new strings to get added like shown below using `next` node. Also for the node you need to make sure `head` is always at beginning of the list.

Third, you need to `break` when list is printed successfully else you end up a `while(1)` loop forever.

```
int main() {
  struct node *head = NULL, *next = NULL, *cur = NULL;
  char input[32];

  while(1) {
    printf("Enter words: ");
    scanf("%s", input);

    if (strcmp(input, "END") != 0) {
      cur = malloc(sizeof(struct node));
      cur->next = NULL;
      strcpy(cur->word, input);
      if (head == NULL) {
        head = cur;
        next = head;
      }
      next->next = cur;
    } else {
      struct node *iter = head;
      while (iter != NULL) {
        printf("Contents: %s\n", iter->word);
        iter = iter->next;
      }
      break;
    }
 }
```